# How to store Spatial data of Circle in SQL Server 2012 in C# WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, sql-server-2012, spatial

I am new to Spatial Data.
My Project is based on Entity Framework 5, .NET 4.5 C#, WPF.

I have managed to store POINT, LINE in SQL 2012 database with geometry data type & DBGeometry data type in  C#.

I am wondering how could I handle Circle in both environments.
In WPF I am drawing circle as ELLIPSE & I am not able to determine way to draw circle as points collection.
(Although in SQL With Point & STBuffer() method we can draw a circle shape).

Does any body knows how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use circularstring to generate circles (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/circularstring?view=sql-server-ver15).

```sql
SELECT CAST('CIRCULARSTRING(1 1, 2 2, 3 1, 2 0, 1 1)' AS GEOMETRY)
```